# The shrinking sphere example

Tags: differential-geometry, ricci-flow

I am having some issues with the vocabulary employed by authors when they refer to some solutions of the Ricci flow equation. For instance, the *shrinking sphere* example.

It seems odd to me when I read "the sphere shrinks to a point **since** $\partial_t g = -2 \text{Ric}(g)$ yields a solution of the form $g(t) = (1-\lambda t)g_0$, where $\lambda >0$, which goes to zero as $t\to 1/\lambda$".

Indeed, the Ricci flow equation acts on the metric alone and considering the vector field $\partial_t$ to solve the Ricci flow equation implicitly requires (at least from my understanding) a fixed manifold.

Instead, my understanding of the fact that one can see this as a shrinking sphere comes from the following:

- **One may allow the manifold to vary with time**, then the one-parameter family $M(t) = (1-\lambda t)\mathbb{S}^n$ for $t \in [0,1/\lambda)$ admits precisely $g(t) = (1-\lambda t)g_0$ as its canonical metric. In this setting the Ricci flow equation is slightly different ($\partial_t$ is replaced by the Lie derivative of some appropriate time vector field $v$, i.e $\mathcal{L}_v$) however one can check that $g(t)$ still solves the equation.

Since I did not find this argument clearly stated, could anyone tells me if this is the right way of understanding the situation? Or else, what am I missing? Thank you for the help.

Comment: The metric is changing, in fact starting at the standard sphere, then at time $t$ you see a sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-2(n-1)t}$; this goes to $0$ as $t\to \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$, thus it is a "shrinking" sphere. You may also want to view this in the Gromov-Hausdorff distance.

Comment: Indeed, the metric is changing. But how to properly understand the fact that the manifold is also changing? It seems to me that this require the little gymnastic on a space-time manifold that I mentioned to properly say: the sphere shrinks. No?

Comment: Before singularities occur, "the manifold is changing" does not mean (for example) the topology is changing, it just means the metric is changing.

Comment: So it is just a vocabulary issue? When you say that "we see a sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-2(n-1)t}$", am I to understand "the metric is the one of a sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-2(n-1)t}$" and nothing else? As I mentioned, the latter is clear to me while the former statement makes sense to me only in the context of space-time manifold.

Comment: The "we see..." is just colorful language. "The metric is the one..." is correct and what the authors mean.